# Specifying the Language of Thesis in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, languages, thesis

I want to cite a Ph.D. dissertation which is not in English; but I want the language be mentioned **out of** the title's apostophe. For example, I am interested in the output

> J. Doe, "This is the dissertation title," (in Latin), Ph.D. dissertation, University of Nowhere, Nowhere, 2021.

Assume that the actual `.tex` file is

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

The Ph.D. thesis of J. Doe~\cite{reference1}.


\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\end{document}
```

One option for the `references.bib` file is

```
@phdthesis{reference1,
author = {John Doe},
title = {This is the dissertation title (in Latin)},
school = {University of Nowhere},
address = {Nowhere},
year = {2021},
}
```

however, it is clear that it writes the language within the title's apostrophe, which is not desired. I added the option

```
language = {Latin},
```

but nothing happended. Any help?

Comment: The question is tagged with both `biblatex` and BibTeX, but the answer here will not only depend on whether or not you use `biblatex` or BibTeX, but also on the exact style you are using. With `biblatex` `language` would be the right field, but instead of `Latin` you'd better say `langlatin` as in `language = {latin},` so that the string is translated. With BibTeX you probably have to find a style-dependent workaround, so please let us know (ideally in a short example document) what style you are using.

Comment: @moewe thanks for your reply. I am using ```bibtex```. I would remove the ```biblatex``` tag.

Comment: Alright. Since the BibTeX world is not that uniform outside a core set of fields (which does not include a field for the document language), a good solution here will depend on the bibliography style you intend to use. Please consider adding that piece of information to the question (ideally you'd show us the style in a minimal working example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). You could try the field `note`, but its position may be quite variable, so it may only look good in some (or indeed no) styles.

Comment: @moewe , I eddited teh question and I wish that the question is well stated now. Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: With `ieeetran` you get an optional note for the `phdthesis` that shows up at the end of the line. So if you put `note={dissertation in Latin}` you would get a note at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Two options. I would personally prefer the second.

1. Very hackish and depends strongly on exactly how `ieeetran` outputs the `.bbl` file. You define in the main document a new command `\inlatin` that eats the trailing `,''` and prints out `,'' (in latin)` instead. And you modify your bib entry to have `title = {....\inlatin}`.
2. Add a `note` field. This makes the `bib` file portable, but where the "note" is displayed depends on the style file.

Examples showing both outputs.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\def\inlatin,''{,'' (in latin)}

\begin{document}

The Ph.D. thesis of J. Doe~\cite{reference1}.

\cite{referencenote}

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\end{document}
```

with `references.bib`

```
@phdthesis{reference1,
author = {John Doe},
title = {This is the dissertation title\inlatin},
school = {University of Nowhere},
address = {Nowhere},
year = {2021},
}

@phdthesis{referencenote,
author = {John Doe},
title = {This is the dissertation title},
school = {University of Nowhere},
address = {Nowhere},
year = {2021},
note = {Dissertation in Latin}
}
```

yields

[image]